# getting the value of Select input on change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get the value of the selected option in a Select input but it isn't working. It should be displaying an alert box when I change the option, but nothing is happening. Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<?PHP

$content ="";
$mammalArray = array();
$otherArray = array();
array_push($mammalArray,"dog");
array_push($mammalArray,"cat");
array_push($mammalArray,"pig");
array_push($otherArray,"bird");
array_push($otherArray,"fish");


$content .= "<select><option value='0'>Please Select a Pet Item</option>";
$content .= "<optgroup label='Mammals'>";

foreach($mammalArray as $animal=>$pet)
{
    $content .= "<option>" . $pet . "</option>";
}

$content .= "</optgroup><optgroup label='Other'>";

foreach($otherArray as $animal=>$pet)
{
   $content .= "<option>" . $pet . "</option>";
}
$content .= "</optgroup></select>";
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $("select").change(function(){
            // Do something here.
            //alert("hello");
            var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
            alert(option);
            });
        </script>

</head>
<body>
<?php
echo($content);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first, value in <option> missing? (    $content .= "<option value=".$pet.">" . $pet . "</option>";?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options have no values so you need to update your `foreach` loops to include one. For example:-

```
foreach($mammalArray as $animal=>$pet)
{
    $content .= '<option value="' . $pet . '">' . $pet . '</option>';
}
```

Then update your jQuery so that it is wrapped in `$(function() {});` to make sure the document is ready before running:-

```
$(function() {
   $("select").change(function(){
       var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
      alert(option);
   });
)};
```

Without setting the `value` attribute of your `<option>` tags there will be no value for `$(this).find('option:selected').val();`.

Answer (score 3):

You have no value in your options and you need to wrap following around your script:

```
$(function() {
   $("select").change(function(){
       var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
      alert(option);
   });
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is being executed before your HTML is set in the DOM. Either wrap your code in a `$(document).on('ready')` handler or place it just before your `</body>`, after your HTML:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        alert(option);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("change", "select", function () {
        // Do something here.
        //alert("hello");
        var option = $(this).val();
        alert(option);
    });
</script>
```